# SQL Merge Statement using stored proc as source

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, merge

I am looking to do something like this but it doesn't compile. My stored proc returns a table. Here's what I am trying to do - maybe someone can point to what I am doing wrong as this doesn't compile:

```
MERGE table AS target
   USING (EXEC [dbo].[sp_Something] @Rundate = '5/13/2011', @SPID = 56) 
      AS source (<Columns Returned By Stored Proc Go Here>)
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Field = Value...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( Field )
         VALUES (Value);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A stored procedure cannot be used where tables are expected.  You must either use a table variable, subquery or a table-valued function.   For example (not sure if this is valid, I've never used `MERGE` before):

```
DECLARE @Something TABLE (columns go here...)

INSERT @Something
EXEC [dbo].[sp_Something] @Rundate = '5/13/2011', $SPID = 56

MERGE table as target
    USING @Something
       AS Source ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only to `INSERT ... EXEC`. The workaround is to spool into a #temp table or a @table variable and use that for the MERGE.

Comment: thought so... Just a lot of columns need to be defined in the @table... Oh well..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I create functions or views that return what an sproc would, and then write the sproc to just call the view/function. That way I encapsulate logic, am able to use the query in joins, and leverage sproc features.

Comment: As long as the sproc uses no side-effects, such as dynamic SQL.

Comment: I don't know if this is right. In SQL Server sproc doesn't have a concrete set of fields that it returns. I don't believe you can use sprocs in VIEWS or UDFs. Maybe the poster is talking about some other database?